# Thread.sleep() Never Returns

Tags: java, sleep

I am having an odd error with `Thread.sleep()` on Java.  For some reason, when I call sleep on some machines, it never returns.  I can't figure out what could be causing this behaviour.  At first, I thgouth the error might be elsewhere in my code, so I made the simplest possible sleep test:

```
public class SleepTest {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println ("Before sleep...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep (100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println ("After sleep...");
    }
}
```

On most machines it works, but on several machines which I am remotely logging into, it pauses indefinitely between the print statements.  I have waited up to a half an hour with no change in behaviour.  The machines that are displaying this error are Linux machines.  Here is some information about the machines:

```
$ uname -a
Linux zone29ea 2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 15 17:16:46 CDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.6) (rhel-1.43.1.10.6.el6_2-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

What could be causing this behaviour?

UPDATE

Revised version, which still never ends:

```
public class SleepTest {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new Thread () {
            public void run () {
                System.out.println ("Before sleep...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep (100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
                System.out.println ("After sleep...");
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check if there is an error fired inside your catch ? maybe a printStackTrace?

Comment: could you try that in a seperate thread to make sure that that still occurs? what you are doing is putting the main thread to sleep which could cause the issue

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't in the recuperation of the second println (as you do it remotely) ? Maybe a missing flush ? `Thread.sleep(100);` works even on linux.

Comment: @AdelBoutros I think if there was an error the program would teminate (and print the "after....")

Comment: do you have the possibility to run the code inside a profiler, such as jvisualvm and get some debug info on the matter?

Comment: You could try running the jvm inside `strace -f`. That way you should be able to see what the app is doing. Although the `futex` calls I see aren't particularly helpful.

Comment: Very interesting question. What happens if you add a `finally` clause ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if your server is running under Linux, you may be hit by the [Leap Second bug](http://it.slashdot.org/story/12/07/01/1920217/leap-second-bug-causes-crashes) which appears last week-end.

This bug affects the Linux kernel (the Thread management), so application which uses threads (as the JVM, mysql etc...) may consume high load of CPU.

Comment: No, the leap second was added in the last minute of the last hour of the last day of June. But the NTP process of you server may have a problem. Rebooting may solve the problem.

Comment: I'll look into this.  The error did start after July 1 and these machines use NTP.

Comment: So the bug is a really good candidate. Rebooting the servers should solve your issue.

Comment: I was able to get physical access to reboot the machines today and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If your servers uses NTP (as you mentioned) and your CPU usage goes to 100%, check for `Clock: inserting leap second 23:59:60 UTC` in your `dmesg:`, if you find that, you are sure that your server affected with `Leap Second bug`, unfortunately Java is the one which is most effected.

To resolve this, with out restarting any servers (like, tomcat) run the following commands.

```
/etc/init.d/ntp stop
date `date +"%m%d%H%M%C%y.%S"`
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't have root access to try this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This does seem to be leap second related.

Based on a post at from https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/7/1/19, I did:

```
date -s "`date`"
```

and it fixed the problem for me