# Is working of "Thread.sleep(30000)" same on Windows and Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a doubt about whether working of "Thread.sleep()" on Windows and Linux is same?

Right now i am working on a enterprise application and i am using spring mvc frame work. Now problem is, I have this line "Thread.sleep(30000)" in one of my function. The value "30000" here indicates "30 seconds" of sleep and it works fine on my local system(Windows os). when I deployed my application on Linux server, i am getting doubt that "Thread.sleep(30000)" is not working as expected.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294573/thread-sleep-never-returns

Comment: my concern is about value "30000". Some post on Google says 30000=30 seconds(on windows) and 30=30seconds(on Linux).

Comment: Just check the authoritative documentation. Forget about all the BS you will find when googling.

Comment: yes, it is same on both windows as well as Linux. May be there is something else in your application causing this unexpected behavior.

Comment: Try to avoid using Thread.Sleep, you should use a timer/scheduler instead...

Answer (score 1):

if your server is running under Linux, you may be hit by the Leap Second bug

see here [Leap Second bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294573/thread-sleep-never-returns)

Comment: my concern is about value "30000". Some post on Google says 30000=30 seconds(on windows) and 30=30seconds(on Linux).